# python: why a File object cannot be pickled?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand why sending a django `InMemoryUploadedFile` object cannot be pickled when sending it as an argument of a celery task, `Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed`. So i tried out the `File` object, doesn't work as well, but a `StringIO` would work.

Need some dummies' guidance in understanding the difference between the 3.

thanks!

Comment: Can you read the StringIO first, then pickle the string?

Comment: yea using StringIO is fine, but i just wanna know the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not allow pickling of some functions either, because of security problems if it were to be allowed. (It depends - there are ways to pickle some functions by reference)

Pickling file objects has been requested in the features threads of python many times, and the best reasoning is because it opens up additional hack vectors into the security processes of python, by allowing run-time injections of potentially malicious events.

It would be very convenient to have in a number of ways, but it appears to be a security restriction.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to security concerns? Pickle itself is not *at all* meant to be safe, meaning that you indeed *can* easily craft pickled objects that will cause the "unpickler" to run arbitrary code -- including open(), of course..